# Spring security multiple login page giving Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have checked many similar questions but could not solve my problem.
I have the following two httpsecurity for admin and user.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AdminSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .antMatcher("/admin/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin-login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/admin-login")
                .failureUrl("/admin-login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/admin-logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin-login?logout")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class UserSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .antMatcher("/user/home/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/home/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user-login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/user-login")
                .failureUrl("/user-login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/user-logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/user-login?logout")
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.builder();
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(users.username("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user")).roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(users.username("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("USER", "ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }

}
```

Whenever I try to login to either admin or user side, I get the following error.

```
2021-03-11 16:46:31.357  WARN 1468 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the repo to reproduce the problem.
https://github.com/venustulips/ss-2-login

Comment: You have <form th:action="@{/admin-login}" method="post"> so you also need a PostMapping in your controller that is called when you hit login in

Comment: The URL of your login page `/user-login` doesn't match your configured path `/user/home/**`. Same for admin.

Comment: you have declared that `.loginPage("/user-login")` here YOU will serve a login page on a `GET` request. which you do. Then you declare `.loginProcessingUrl("/admin-login")` so you are telling spring security that there you will provide a custom `POST` endpoint that will process the username and password, which you have NOT currently defined

Comment: if you have no idea, then i suggest you start out building one login using springs default values, and make sure that works so you understand what you are doing before you start doing double logins with custom login endpoints.

Comment: You code from github has changed a bit from the question. Seems you moved the admin logins under `/admin/login` rather than the previous `/admin-login`. Assuming this, it seems you have a simple issue where your `login.html` still points to `action=@{/admin-login}` rather than `action=@{/admin/login}`. Also your `.defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")` is served as a POST endpoint which should actually be a GET endpoint.

You do not need to provide an implementation for `.loginProcessingUrl("/admin-login")`. Spring Security does that for you.

Comment: @jms, Yes code has changed, I am testing based on feedback from here. Thanks for checking it. BTW I am making some progress by removing `loginProcessingUrl`.

Comment: `loginProcessingUrl` is there to provide an alternative url that spring will use to process the credentials. This was introduced to make the login path configurable and also make it unobvious to an external party to see that this application is using Spring-Security to secure the application, which can be assumed if the default `/j_spring_security_check` is used in Spring Versions <= 4. There is no problem in having it and you don't have to do anything additional to support it.

Comment: I would also like to add that your initial question has an interesting concern. Your admin websecurity is configured for `http.antMatcher("/admin/**")`. As a result, a post to the following `.loginProcessingUrl("/admin-login")` will not apply the necessary SpringSecurityFilterChain (since the path doesn't match). Changing to `.loginProcessingUrl("/admin/login")` as in your code resolved that issue for you